# position button next to each other

Tags: html, css, button

I want to display my Back and Confirm button next to each other. As you can see I tried doing display:inline-block but it didn't work. I think there might be some conflicting codes but I'm not sure where it is. This might be a dumb question but bear with me please.

Here's my code:

```css
.form__confirmation {
  padding: 0px 55px;
}

.form__confirmation2 {
  padding: 0px 55px;
}

button {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: #011f4b;
  border: 1px solid #DADDE8;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition: background-color 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  position: relative;
  left: 350px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #1293e1;
}

button:active {
  background-color: #1083c8;
}
```

```html
<div class="form__confirmation" type="submit" name="submit">
  <button>Confirm Information</button>
</div>
<div class="form__confirmation2">
  <button>Back</button>
</div>
```

[image: Here's what it looks like]

Comment: You should be declaring `display: inline-block` on the parent elements of `button`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.form__confirmation,.form__confirmation2 {
      display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="form__confirmation" type="submit" name="submit">
  <button>Confirm Information</button>
</div>
<div class="form__confirmation2">
  <button>Back</button>
</div>
```

You are placing them within `div` elements, which are `display:block` by default. Either include both buttons within the same `div` or use `div{display:inline-block}`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply display: inline-block; to your container Like so:

```css
.form__confirmation {
    padding: 0px 55px;
      display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .form__confirmation2 {
    padding: 0px 55px;
      display: inline-block;
  }

  button {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background-color: #011f4b;
    border: 1px solid #DADDE8;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4,       0, 0.2, 1);
    transition: background-color 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2,       1);
    position: relative;
    left: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  button:hover {
    background-color: #1293e1;
  }
  button:active {
    background-color: #1083c8;
  }
```

```html
<div class="form__confirmation" type="submit" name="submit">
  <button>Confirm Information</button>
</div>
<div class="form__confirmation2">
  <button>Back</button>
</div>
```